# boost::asio::spawn yield as callback

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, coroutine

I'm trying to rewrite a project using `boost::asio::spawn` coroutines. Some parts of the project cannot be changed. For example, the storage protocol library is also written with `boost::asio`, but without coroutines.

The problem is how to convert `yield_context` into a normal callback (a `boost::function` object or a classical functor).

This is what we have in the storage library API:

```
void async_request_data(uint64_t item_id, boost::function< void(Request_result *) > callback);
```

As we know from examples, the asio yield context can be used like this:

```
    my_socket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data), yield);
```

In this case a `boost::asio::yield_context` object serves as a callback for **async_read_some**. I would like to pass  a **yield** object as the second argument to `async_request_data`, so i can use it in  a synchronous manner.

How can this be done? I think it may be possible via some proxy-object, possibly using an approach based on **asio_handler_invoke**.  But I am having trouble seeing how to do this.

Comment: The accepted answer below no longer works with more recent versions of Boost. But there is an answer here that works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60016315/245265

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looks like the best documentation for this feature can be found in a C++ standard proposal written by the boost asio author:

[N4045 – Library Foundations for Asynchronous Operations, Revision 2](http://www.open-std.org/Jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4045.pdf)

See section 9.1 which says:

```
handler_type_t<CompletionToken, void(error_code, size_t)>   #3
  handler(std::forward<CompletionToken>(token));
```

> 3: The completion token is converted into a handler, i.e. a function object to be called
>   when the asynchronous operation completes. The signature specifies the arguments
>   that will be passed to the handler.

I guess in your case the `CompletionToken` template argument will actually be `boost::asio::yield_context` and `handler_type` converts it to a callback object.

---

Here is the code from section 9.1 updated to call your `async_request_data` function:

```
template <class CompletionToken>
auto async_foo(uint64_t item_id, CompletionToken&& token)
{
  handler_type_t<CompletionToken, void(Request_result *)>
    handler(std::forward<CompletionToken>(token));

  async_result<decltype(handler)> result(handler);  

  async_request_data(item_id, handler);

  return result.get();  
}
```

Comment: Surely, i need some proxy object to pass it as callback, but its not clear how to write this object's guts. `yield_context` does not have `operator()` (othewise it would work "as is" without proxy). It has some guts described here http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_yield_context/basic_yield_context.html , but its not clear how to combine them to do a correct coroutine resume.

Comment: I think `handler` **is** the proxy object. Pls see edit.

Comment: It worked with some little changes! Thanks for directions! (I posted final code in another answer)

Comment: Thank you @free_coffee and @PSIAlt! This trick will allow my upcoming Asio-based library to provide both handler and coroutine-based APIs without having to implement everything twice!

Comment: This answer no longer works with more recent versions of Boost. But there is an answer here that works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60016315/245265

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to @PSIAlt and @free_coffee I know how to use callback functions in stackful coroutine.

Here is a simple example just for asio newbies(like me :D)

https://gist.github.com/chenfengyuan/4d764b0bca82a42c05a9

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/spawn.hpp>
#include <memory>

void bar(boost::asio::io_service &io, std::function<void()> cb){
    auto ptr = std::make_shared<boost::asio::deadline_timer>(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
    ptr->async_wait([ptr, cb](const boost::system::error_code&){cb();});
}

template<typename Handler>
void foo(boost::asio::io_service &io, Handler && handler){
    typename boost::asio::handler_type<Handler, void()>::type handler_(std::forward<Handler>(handler));
    boost::asio::async_result<decltype(handler_)> result(handler_);
    bar(io, handler_);
    result.get();
    return;
}

int main()
{
  boost::asio::io_service io;
  boost::asio::spawn(io, [&io](boost::asio::yield_context yield){
      foo(io, yield);
      std::cout << "hello, world!\n";
  });

  io.run();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice minimal example!  There is a subtle problem.  `handler_`  must invoked through the [`asio_handler_invoke()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/asio_handler_invoke.html) hook to properly synchronize with the coroutine.  Otherwise, in a multi-threaded environment, a race condition may occur where the coroutine is attempted to be resumed before it has yielded.  The `asio_handler_invoke` hook is overloaded for specific types, so type erasure to `std::function<>` cannot occur.  [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c48d1dcf4608e967) is an updated solution.

Answer (score 3):

---

Great thanks to **free_coffe** i managed this to work. Posting solution for my case, possibly someone need it.

```
template <class CompletionToken>
RequestResult async_foo(Packet &pkt, CompletionToken&& token) {
   typename boost::asio::handler_type< CompletionToken, void(RequestResult) >::type handler( std::forward<CompletionToken>(token) );
  boost::asio::async_result<decltype(handler)> result(handler);
  storage_api->writePacket(pkt, handler);
  return result.get();
}
```

Later we can use this proxy:

```
RequestResult res = async_foo(pkt, std::forward<boost::asio::yield_context>(yield) );
```

Comment: Great! Doesn't smell quite right using a `detail` class though. Maybe you can post the errors from when you tried to use `handler_type`?

Comment: @free_coffee `error: could not convert ‘result.boost::asio::async_result<Handler>::get<boost::asio::basic_yield_context<boost::asio::detail::wrapped_handler<boost::asio::io_service::strand, void (*)(), boost::asio::detail
::is_continuation_if_running> > >()’ from ‘boost::asio::async_result<boost::asio::basic_yield_context<boost::asio::detail::wrapped_handler<boost::asio::io_service::strand, void (*)(), boost::asio::detail::is_continuation_if_running> > >:
:type {aka void}’ to ‘RequestResult’`

Comment: It looks like the `yield_context` is somehow being passed as the `async_result` template parameter, meaning `decltype(handler)` is not what it should be. Could you post the code?

Comment: @free_coffee sure, here is it https://gist.github.com/PSIAlt/d4c9ccf48b962f797efd

Comment: I think the second template argument to `handler_type` is supposed to be a function signature, so `handler_type<CompletionToken, void(RequestResult)>` rather than `handler_type<CompletionToken, RequestResult>`.

Comment: @free_coffee omg it worked! Also works safely with thread pool. Great, thanks! Updated to "correct" version.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, one can treat callback handlers and `yield_context` (as well as `use_awaitable` and `use_future`) uniformly as [completions tokens](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/model/completion_tokens.html) that are accepted via a templatized argument. The token is then transformed into a handler function that is passed to an *initiating function* via `boost::asio::async_initiate`:

```cpp
// This is the API function
template <typename CompletionToken>
auto async_request_db_data(uint64_t item_id, CompletionToken&& token)
{
    // If you can't use C++14 generic lambdas, then use a function
    // object instead with an operator() template member function.
    auto init = [](auto completion_handler, uint64_t item_id)
    {
        init_request_db_data(item_id, std::move(completion_handler));
    }

    // void(database_result) is the signature of the intermediary
    // handler function that is passed to the initiating function.
    return boost::asio::async_initiate<Token, void(database_result)>(
        init, std::forward<CompletionToken>(token));

}

// This is a private function that does the actual work.
template <typename CompletionHandler>
void init_request_db_data(uint64_t item_id, CompletionHandler handler)
{
    // Perform actual work and then post handler when complete,
    // passing the database_result.
    // Note the handler below is moved because some completion handlers
    // are move-only (particularly those originating from use_awaitable).

    auto exec = boost::asio::get_associated_executor(handler);
    boost::asio::post(exec, std::bind(std::move(handler), db_result);
}

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_context ioctx;

    // API used with stackful coroutine yield_context
    boost::asio::spawn(
        ioctx,
        [](boost::asio_yield_context yield)
        {
            auto result = async_request_db_data(42, yield);
        });

    // API used with traditional callback handler
    async_request_db_data(
        42,
        [](database_result result)
        {
            // Do something with result
        }

    ioctx.run();
}
```

If you need to type-erase the handler passed to the initiating function (because you want the implementation to be compiled from a cpp file), then check out the experimental [any_completion_handler](https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/blob/any-completion-handler/asio/include/asio/any_completion_handler.hpp) that the author of Boost.Asio has recently written (see [related feature request](https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/issues/1100))