# boost::asio::yield_context: unexpected forced_unwind exception

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, coroutine

I'm tring to write my custom async function for boost::asio as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24497881/boostasiospawn-yield-as-callback).

However I'm getting boost::coroutines::detail::forced_unwind exception on line with **result.get**

```
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/spawn.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/steady_timer.hpp>

#include <iostream>

namespace asio = ::boost::asio;


template <typename Timer, typename Token>
auto my_timer (Timer& timer, Token&& token)
{
  typename asio::handler_type<Token,
      void (::boost::system::error_code const)>::type
      handler (std::forward<Token> (token));

  asio::async_result<decltype (handler)> result (handler);

  timer.async_wait (handler);
  return result.get (); // Got forced_unwind exception here.
}

int main ()
{
  asio::io_service io;
  asio::steady_timer timer (io, ::boost::chrono::seconds (1));

  asio::spawn (io, [&] (asio::yield_context yield)
      {
      try {
        std::cout << "my_timer enter\n";
        my_timer (timer, yield);
        std::cout << "my_timer returns\n";
      }
      catch (const boost::coroutines::detail::forced_unwind& e)
      { 
        std::cout << "boost::coroutines::detail::forced_unwind\n"; 
      }
    }
  );

  io.run ();
}
```

Same code on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/119690d6c24abe00)

**UPDATE**:

The behavior exists on:

```
Darwin 14.0.0 (MacOS 10.10) 
clang version 3.6.0 (trunk 216817) and gcc version 4.9.1 (MacPorts gcc49 4.9.1_1) 
boost 1.57
```

and

```
Red Hat 6.5
gcc version 4.7.2 20121015 (Red Hat 4.7.2-5) (GCC)
boost 1.57 and 1.56
(the example code was trivially modified because gcc 4.7 does not support c++14 mode)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In short, you need to create a copy of handler, such as by posting it into the `io_service`, before attempting to get the `async_result` in order to keep the coroutine alive.

---

Boost.Asio prevents a non-resumable coroutine from indefinitely suspending by destroying the coroutine, resulting in the coroutine's stack to unwind.  The coroutine object will throw `boost::coroutines::detail::forced_unwind` during its destruction, causing the suspended stack to unwind.  Asio accomplishes this by:

- The [`yield_context`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/yield_context.html) CompletionToken maintains a `weak_ptr` to the coroutine.
- When the specialized [`handler_type::type`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/handler_type.html) handler is constructed, it obtains a `shared_ptr` for the coroutine via the CompletionToken's `weak_ptr`.  When the handler is passed as the completion handler to asynchronous operations, the handler and its `shared_ptr` are copied.  When the handler is invoked, it resumes the coroutine.
- When invoking [`async_result::get()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_result/get.html), the specialization will reset the coroutine `shared_ptr` owned by the handler that was passed to `async_result` during construction, and then yield the coroutine.

Here is an attempt to illustrate the execution of the code.  Paths in `|` indicate the active stack, `:` indicates the suspended stack, and arrows are used to indicate transfer of control:

```
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
boost::asio::spawn(io_service, &my_timer);
`-- dispatch a coroutine creator
    into the io_service.
io_service.run();
|-- invoke the coroutine entry
|   handler.
|   |-- create coroutine
|   |   (count: 1)
|   |-- start coroutine        ----> my_timer()
:   :                                |-- create handler1 (count: 2)
:   :                                |-- create asnyc_result1(handler1)
:   :                                |-- timer.async_wait(handler)
:   :                                |   |-- create handler2 (count: 3)
:   :                                |   |-- create async_result2(handler2)
:   :                                |   |-- create operation and copy
:   :                                |   |   handler3 (count: 4)
:   :                                |   `-- async_result2.get()
:   :                                |       |-- handler2.reset() (count: 3)
|   `-- return                 <---- |       `-- yield
|       `-- ~entry handler           :
|           (count: 2)               :
|-- io_service has work (the         :
|   async_wait operation)            :
|   ...async wait completes...       :
|-- invoke handler3                  :
|   |-- resume                 ----> |-- async_result1.get()
:   :                                |   |--  handler1.reset() (count: 1)
|   `-- return                 <---- |   `-- yield
|       `-- ~handler3                :       :
|           |  (count: 0)            :       :
|           `-- ~coroutine()   ----> |       `-- throw forced_unwind
```

To fix this problem, `handler` needs to be copied and invoked through [`asio_handler_invoke()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/asio_handler_invoke.html) when it is time to resume the coroutine.  For example, the following will post a completion handler<sup>1</sup> into `io_service` that invokes a copy of `handler`:

```cpp
timer.async_wait (handler);

timer.get_io_service().post(
  std::bind([](decltype(handler) handler)
  {
    boost::system::error_code error;
    // Handler must be invoked through asio_handler_invoke hooks
    // to properly synchronize with the coroutine's execution
    // context.
    using boost::asio::asio_handler_invoke;
    asio_handler_invoke(std::bind(handler, error), &handler);
  }, handler)
);
return result.get ();
```

As demonstrated [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/83fc20785c1412e9), with this additional code, the output becomes:

```
my_timer enter
my_timer returns
```

---

<sub>1. The completion handler code can likely be cleaned up a bit, but as I was answering [how to resume a Boost.Asio stackful coroutine from a different thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26728121/1053968), I observed some compilers selecting the wrong `asio_handler_invoke` hook.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for the answer. After few cups of coffee I understood why posted std::bind handler is always called after coroutine destruction, even in multithreaded io_service execution environment :) However, such design seems to me to be over-complicated and error prone to my taste :(

Comment: I also found an alternative solution: to use a wrapper that holds the copy of the handler and thus prevents the early coroutine destruction. Code: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b639954744728c43 What do you think? Is it reasonable?

Comment: @Nikki  Glad to help.  The `std::bind` handler is not called after the destruction of the coroutine; instead, it keeps the coroutine alive as it has a copy of `handler` which holds a `shared_ptr` to the coroutine.  The desired goal was not clear to me, so the code I posted was focused on demonstrating proper handler invocation and coroutine yielding.  The latest code you posted is functionally very different.  What is the desired goal?  When an asynchronous operation is initiated, do you wish to be able to do additional work in the coroutine _before_ yielding, or should it yield immediately?

Answer (score 4):

This is a Boost Coroutine implementation detail.

As documented here: ***[exceptions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/coroutine/doc/html/coroutine/coroutine/asymmetric.html#coroutine.coroutine.asymmetric.exceptions)***

> ## ⚠ Important
>
> Code executed by coroutine-function must not prevent the propagation of the `detail::forced_unwind exception`. Absorbing that exception will cause stack unwinding to fail. Thus, any code that catches all exceptions must re-`throw` any pending `detail::forced_unwind` exception.

So, you're explicitly **required** to pass this exception through. Explicitly code the handler like:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/93fe4c7954ea1051)</kbd>**

```
try {
  std::cout << "my_timer enter\n";
  my_timer(timer, yield);
  std::cout << "my_timer returns\n";
}
catch (boost::coroutines::detail::forced_unwind const& e)
{ 
   throw; // required for Boost Coroutine!
}
catch (std::exception const& e)
{ 
   std::cout << "exception '" << e.what() << "'\n";
}
```

This particular exception is an implementation detail and must

- be expected in coroutine context
- not be swallowed, or RAII semantics will be violated leading to resource leaks and possibly undefined behaviours with your RAII type.

To be fair, this makes it unsafe to "naively" use existing (legacy) code that might not afford this guarantee. I think this is very strong reason for

- guidelines against non-specific catches except to *bare* rethrow
- centralized exception strategies (like **[using a Lippincott function](http://cppsecrets.blogspot.nl/2013/12/using-lippincott-function-for.html) for exception handlers**)

  Beware that last idea might be expressly prohibited in Coroutines too:

  > ## ⚠ Important
  >
  > Do not jump from inside a catch block and than re-throw the exception in another execution context.

  *Update:* As @DeadMG just commented on that article, we can trivially transform the Lippincott function to a wrapping function, which could satisfy the requirements for Coroutine while centralizing exception handling.

Comment: @sehe you are right, my sample code was not correct and I missed forced_unwind rethrow. However, please notice that even with the rethrow added by you the code does not work as expected. I would expect "my_timer enter" AND "my_timer return" output, but actually I got only "my_timer enter" message. I bet that you could see the same with boost 1.54 and VM.

Comment: @NikkiChumakov Yes. I think that there is something else the matter. Could it be that the result type of the handler is deduced as void? (I replaced `auto` by `void` to compile at c++11). That seems to be a reason for Boost Coroutine to unwind

Comment: I don't know what is the reason, just tring to find it out. :) What I noticed is if I wrap the async_wait handler with some trivial wrapper class or even with lambda everything works as expected. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c498fe675ce4ccde

Comment: That would be because different specializations/ADL overloads are then selected for the `async_result` trait and `handler_invoke` customization point. (To be honest, I'm not up to speed with what you're trying to achieve here. I was kinda assuming you knew :))

Comment: What I want to achieve is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24497881/boostasiospawn-yield-as-callback I.e. I want to convert yield_context object into callable object and use it legacy code that is written on top of boost::asio. In my sample code I pass handler directly to asio::async_wait and in real code I would pass it to some legacy function that may pass it later to asio::async_wait or may call it directly according to its internal logic.

Comment: It may be a good cause to phrase your question /that/ way (or post a new one) focusing on the design goals, instead of the incidental implementation mishaps encountered. (I'd figure that people like Tanner Sansbury would be able to shed some light there.)

Comment: forced_unwind is thrown if the coroutine (yield_context) is deconstructed (used  for stack unwinding). find out why yield_context is destroyed too early.

Comment: I did not see this question until today, but the gist is that Boost.Asio prevents a coroutine from staying indefinitely suspended if it knows that there are no handlers available to resume it.  When this occurs, Boost.Asio will destroy the coroutine, causing the suspended stack to unwind.