# What's wrong with this boost::asio and boost::coroutine usage pattern?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-asio, valgrind, boost-coroutine

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31610415/what-causes-a-random-crash-in-boostcoroutine) question I described *boost::asio* and *boost::coroutine* usage pattern which causes random crashes of my application and I published extract from my code and *valgrind* and *GDB* output.

In order to investigate the problem further I created smaller *proof of concept* application which applies the same pattern. I saw that the same problem arises in the smaller program which source I publish here.

The code starts a few threads and creates a connection pool with a few dummy connections (user supplied numbers). Additional arguments are unsigned integer numbers which plays the role of fake requests. The dummy implementation of `sendRequest` function just starts asynchronous timer for waiting number of seconds equal to the input number and *yileds* from the function.

Can someone see the problem with this code and can he propose some fix for it?

```
#include "asiocoroutineutils.h"
#include "concurrentqueue.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;
using namespace utils;

#define id this_thread::get_id() << ": "

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

/*!
 * \brief This is a fake Connection class
 */
class Connection
{
public:
    Connection(unsigned connectionId)
        : _id(connectionId)
    {
    }

    unsigned getId() const
    {
        return _id;
    }

    void sendRequest(asio::io_service& ioService,
                     unsigned seconds,
                     AsioCoroutineJoinerProxy,
                     asio::yield_context yield)
    {
        cout << id << "Connection " << getId()
             << " Start sending: " << seconds << endl;

        // waiting on this timer is palceholder for any asynchronous operation
        asio::steady_timer timer(ioService);
        timer.expires_from_now(chrono::seconds(seconds));
        coroutineAsyncWait(timer, yield);

        cout << id << "Connection " << getId()
             << " Received response: " << seconds << endl;
    }

private:
    unsigned _id;
};

typedef std::unique_ptr<Connection> ConnectionPtr;
typedef std::shared_ptr<asio::steady_timer> TimerPtr;

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

class ConnectionPool
{
public:
    ConnectionPool(size_t connectionsCount)
    {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < connectionsCount; ++i)
        {
            cout << "Creating connection: " << i << endl;
            _connections.emplace_back(new Connection(i));
        }
    }

    ConnectionPtr getConnection(TimerPtr timer,
                                asio::yield_context& yield)
    {
        lock_guard<mutex> lock(_mutex);

        while(_connections.empty())
        {
            cout << id << "There is no free connection." << endl;

            _timers.emplace_back(timer);
            timer->expires_from_now(
                asio::steady_timer::clock_type::duration::max());

            _mutex.unlock();
            coroutineAsyncWait(*timer, yield);
            _mutex.lock();

            cout << id << "Connection was freed." << endl;
        }

        cout << id << "Getting connection: "
             << _connections.front()->getId() << endl;

        ConnectionPtr connection = std::move(_connections.front());
        _connections.pop_front();
        return connection;
    }

    void addConnection(ConnectionPtr connection)
    {
        lock_guard<mutex> lock(_mutex);

        cout << id << "Returning connection " << connection->getId()
             << " to the pool." << endl;

        _connections.emplace_back(std::move(connection));

        if(_timers.empty())
            return;

        auto timer = _timers.back();
        _timers.pop_back();
        auto& ioService = timer->get_io_service();

        ioService.post([timer]()
        {
            cout << id << "Wake up waiting getConnection." << endl;
            timer->cancel();
        });
    }

private:
    mutex _mutex;
    deque<ConnectionPtr> _connections;
    deque<TimerPtr> _timers;
};

typedef unique_ptr<ConnectionPool> ConnectionPoolPtr;

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

class ScopedConnection
{
public:
    ScopedConnection(ConnectionPool& pool,
                     asio::io_service& ioService,
                     asio::yield_context& yield)
        : _pool(pool)
    {
        auto timer = make_shared<asio::steady_timer>(ioService);
        _connection = _pool.getConnection(timer, yield);
    }

    Connection& get()
    {
        return *_connection;
    }

    ~ScopedConnection()
    {
        _pool.addConnection(std::move(_connection));
    }

private:
    ConnectionPool& _pool;
    ConnectionPtr _connection;
};

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void sendRequest(asio::io_service& ioService,
                 ConnectionPool& pool,
                 unsigned seconds,
                 asio::yield_context yield)
{
    cout << id << "Constructing request ..." << endl;

    AsioCoroutineJoiner joiner(ioService);

    ScopedConnection connection(pool, ioService, yield);

    asio::spawn(ioService, bind(&Connection::sendRequest,
                                connection.get(),
                                std::ref(ioService),
                                seconds,
                                AsioCoroutineJoinerProxy(joiner),
                                placeholders::_1));

    joiner.join(yield);

    cout << id << "Processing response ..." << endl;
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void threadFunc(ConnectionPool& pool,
                ConcurrentQueue<unsigned>& requests)
{
    try
    {
        asio::io_service ioService;

        while(true)
        {
            unsigned request;
            if(!requests.tryPop(request))
                break;

            cout << id << "Scheduling request: " << request << endl;

            asio::spawn(ioService, bind(sendRequest,
                                        std::ref(ioService),
                                        std::ref(pool),
                                        request,
                                        placeholders::_1));
        }

        ioService.run();
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e)
    {
        cerr << id << "Error: " << e.what() << endl;
    }
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(argc < 3)
    {
        cout << "Usage: ./async_request poolSize threadsCount r0 r1 ..."
             << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    try
    {
        auto poolSize = lexical_cast<size_t>(argv[1]);
        auto threadsCount = lexical_cast<size_t>(argv[2]);

        ConcurrentQueue<unsigned> requests;
        for(int i = 3; i < argc; ++i)
        {
            auto request = lexical_cast<unsigned>(argv[i]);
            requests.tryPush(request);
        }

        ConnectionPoolPtr pool(new ConnectionPool(poolSize));

        vector<unique_ptr<thread>> threads;
        for(size_t i = 0; i < threadsCount; ++i)
        {
            threads.emplace_back(
                new thread(threadFunc, std::ref(*pool), std::ref(requests)));
        }

        for_each(threads.begin(), threads.end(), mem_fn(&thread::join));
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e)
    {
        cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here are some helper utilities used by the above code:

```
#pragma once

#include <boost/asio/steady_timer.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/spawn.hpp>

namespace utils
{

inline void coroutineAsyncWait(boost::asio::steady_timer& timer,
                               boost::asio::yield_context& yield)
{
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    timer.async_wait(yield[ec]);
    if(ec && ec != boost::asio::error::operation_aborted)
        throw std::runtime_error(ec.message());
}

class AsioCoroutineJoiner
{
public:
    explicit AsioCoroutineJoiner(boost::asio::io_service& io)
        : _timer(io), _count(0) {}

    void join(boost::asio::yield_context yield)
    {
        assert(_count > 0);
        _timer.expires_from_now(
            boost::asio::steady_timer::clock_type::duration::max());
        coroutineAsyncWait(_timer, yield);
    }

    void inc()
    {
        ++_count;
    }

    void dec()
    {
        assert(_count > 0);
        --_count;
        if(0 == _count)
            _timer.cancel();
    }

private:
    boost::asio::steady_timer _timer;
    std::size_t _count;

}; // AsioCoroutineJoiner class

class AsioCoroutineJoinerProxy
{
public:
    AsioCoroutineJoinerProxy(AsioCoroutineJoiner& joiner)
        : _joiner(joiner)
    {
        _joiner.inc();
    }

    AsioCoroutineJoinerProxy(const AsioCoroutineJoinerProxy& joinerProxy)
        : _joiner(joinerProxy._joiner)
    {
        _joiner.inc();
    }

    ~AsioCoroutineJoinerProxy()
    {
        _joiner.dec();
    }

private:
    AsioCoroutineJoiner& _joiner;

}; // AsioCoroutineJoinerProxy class

} // utils namespace
```

For completeness of the code the last missing part is **ConcurrentQueue** class. It is too long to paste it here, but if you want you can find it [here](http://pastebin.com/gKLHjbpU).

Example usage of the application is:

> ./connectionpooltest 3 3 5 7 8 1 0 9 2 4 3 6

where the first number 3 are fake connections count and the second number 3 are the number of used threads. Numbers after them are fake requests.

The output of *valgrind* and *GDB* is the same as in the mentioned above [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31610415/what-causes-a-random-crash-in-boostcoroutine).

Used version of *boost* is **1.57**. The compiler is **GCC 4.8.3**. The operating system is **CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503**

Comment: `#define id this_thread::get_id() << ": "` Are you serious?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What causes a random crash in boost::coroutine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31610415/what-causes-a-random-crash-in-boostcoroutine)

Comment: But the code is now complete (it seems) @PSIAlt I'd give it a chance like this

Comment: @erenon You get to minor details. :) This is only *proof of concept*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that all *valgrind* errors are caused because of **BOOST_USE_VALGRIND** macro is not defined as *Tanner Sansbury* points in comment related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29180589/is-it-safe-to-use-spawn-directly-in-an-asio-stackfull-coroutine) question. It seems that except this the program is correct.