# How can I replace deprecated handler_type_t or boost::asio::handler_type in this example code snippet?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost, boost-asio, yield

I found this interesting link
[boost::asio::spawn yield as callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24497881/boostasiospawn-yield-as-callback/24662973#24662973)

and since that might be what I need I wanted to try out the following part:

```
template <class CompletionToken>
auto async_foo(uint64_t item_id, CompletionToken&& token)
{

    typename boost::asio::handler_type< CompletionToken, void(error_code, size_t) >::type handler(std::forward<CompletionToken>(token));
    //handler_type_t<CompletionToken, void(error_code, size_t)>                        handler(std::forward<CompletionToken>(token));

    async_result<decltype(handler)> result(handler);

    //async_request_data(item_id, handler);

    return result.get();
}
```

But obviously neither `handler_type_t` nor `boost::asio::handler_type` is existing anymore in a newer boost version.

How can I adapt the example?

EDIT:

Is that he right way? Instead of

```
boost::asio::handler_type< CompletionToken, void(error_code, size_t) >::type
```

I used

```
typename boost::asio::async_result< CompletionToken, void(error_code, size_t) >::completion_handler_type
```

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73346297/245265

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its almost right.  from the [docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/asynchronous_operations.html) of `boost.asio`

> An initiating function determines the type CompletionHandler of its completion handler function object by performing `typename async_result<decay_t<CompletionToken>, Signature>::completion_handler_type`

and

> An initiating function produces its return type as follows:
>
> — constructing an object result of type `async_result<decay_t<CompletionToken>, Signature>`, initialized as `result(completion_handler);` and
>
> — using `result.get()` as the operand of the return statement.

So correct way to adapt example would be

```
template <class CompletionToken>
auto async_foo(uint64_t item_id, CompletionToken&& token)
{

    typename boost::asio::async_result<std::decay_t<CompletionToken>, void(std::error_code, std::size_t)>::completion_handler_type
                    handler(std::forward<CompletionToken>(token));
    boost::asio::async_result<std::decay_t<CompletionToken>, void(std::error_code, std::size_t)> result(handler);

    async_request_data(item_id, handler);

    return result.get();
}
```

Comment: This does not work with the `use_awaitable` completion token. One must use the new `boost::asio::async_initiate`. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73346297/245265